# Why onreadystatechange has not a method like syntax in this code?

Tags: javascript

My question is why onreadystatechange get a function? Why we could not pass function as a parameter to onreadystatechange instead use of "="?

```
var httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest();

httpreq.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (httpreq.readyState == 4) {
    console.log(httpreq.responseText);
  }
}

httpreq.open('GET', 'DATA/data.json', true);
httpreq.send();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange property contains the event
>   handler to be called when the readystatechange event is fired, that is
>   every time the readyState property of the XMLHttpRequest changes.

That is to allow for an asynchronous function call. Results are handled when they arrive, not when the function finishes running.

That's what callback functions are for. They are invoked when a result is available.

Answer (score 2):

`onreadystatechange`, like many DOM `on-` properties, is a *setter*. When you assign to the property, an *internal function* is actually invoked, that takes the function you assigned to `onreadystatechange` and adds it as an event listener.

```js
// an example of a setter:
const obj = {
  set prop(arg) {
    console.log('set ' + arg);
  }
};

obj.prop = 'newprop';
```

If you wanted to add the listener using a function, you can use `addEventListener` instead:

```
var httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
function listener() {
  if (httpreq.readyState == 4) {
    console.log(httpreq.responseText);
  }
}
httpreq.addEventListener('readystatechange', listener);
httpreq.open('GET', 'DATA/data.json', true);
httpreq.send();
```

The main difference between assigning to an `on-` property and passing a function to `addEventListener` is that `on`-properties can only hold *one* listener at a time. If you assign one listener to an `on` property, and then assign another listener to the same `on` property, the first listener will no longer be active on that element. On the other hand, with `addEventListener`, you can add as many listeners of a particular type as you want.

Most times, when you have something that accepts listeners, you can either assign to an `on<eventname>` property, or you can call `addEventListener('eventname'`. You can use either method, whichever one you're most comfortable with, although if there's a chance you're going to need to add more than one listener of a particular type, best to use `addEventListener` to ensure previous listeners don't get overwritten.

Make sure to remember to only use `on` when *assigning*, with the `=` syntax. `addEventListener('onclick` (or `('on` anything else) won't work - you have to pass the event name alone when using `addEventListener`, and use `on<eventname>` when using `=` to invoke the setter.

As to *why* this is the way things are - it's because the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handlers) says [so](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-idl-attributes).

Comment: Great, but it doesn’t answer the (off-topic) question of why it is a property.